# Getting JSON Files cross domain for all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cors, cross-domain

Hi I have built a web app and everything was working ok until I tested on IE9 with JSON files coming from another domain

Basically all of out JSON files are stored on AMAZON.

The idea on the first load is that I get a site.json file and this initializes and setups the app - but in IE9 and periodically in Safari and Chrome I am getting cross domain errors

So this is some extracts from the head of my homepage

```
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var SiteConfig, frameworkHost;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var promise = $.ajax({
                url: '//s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/****/site.json',
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json'
            });

        $.when(promise).then(function(result) {
                SiteConfig = result.data;
                frameworkHost   = '//s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/**/public_html';

                var requireTag = document.createElement('script');

                requireTag.setAttribute('type',         'text/javascript');
                requireTag.setAttribute('src',          frameworkHost + '/js/require/require.js');
                requireTag.setAttribute('data-main',    frameworkHost + '/js/bootstrap');

                document.head.appendChild(requireTag);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

but the problem is as soon as the url to get site.json is not local on IE9 it fails.

Also in chrome, and safari on iphone 4s with ios 5 on occasions i get this error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/***. Origin It is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

when i clear the cache this works though. It works perfectly on FF.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing the dataType: 'json' to dataType: 'jsop' in your ajax

Comment: no that doesnt work - doesnt load the json

Comment: http://www.cypressnorth.com/blog/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
 // Use Microsoft XDR
 var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
 xdr.open("get", "someurl");
 xdr.onload = function () {
 var JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
 if (JSON == null || typeof (JSON) == 'undefined')
 {
    JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild.textContent);
 }
 processData(JSON);
 };
 xdr.send();
} else {
      $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "someurl",
      processData: true,
      data: {},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) { processData(data); }
      });
}
```